# Old elections are offering vote buttons

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderator-election

Tried both the [2019 election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11?tab=election) and [2018 election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/10?tab=election). I'm presented with voting buttons, as well as whom I voted for in each. You can't actually vote, however.

[image: 2019 voting buttons]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug, because:

> as well as whom I voted for in each.

The UI lets you see how you voted, in two places (on the right, and in the state of the vote buttons).

Look at the candidates you voted for. The '1st', '2nd' and '3rd'  choice buttons look different there; here are the buttons on the candidate I voted for as second choice:

[image: blue voting buttons with 1st, 2nd and 3rd choice labels, with 1st and 3rd choice options dimmed compared to the 2nd choice button]

> You can't actually vote, however.

Exactly. Just like the vote buttons next to your own posts; they don't work either (I can't vote for this answer, but the buttons are there for consistency).

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't taken note before.

Comment: But there's already the banner at the right hand side that shows who you voted for much more conveniently... That said, I don't see a reason to remove the buttons when an election is over

Comment: @Nick only if they voted on that election, otherwise the right-hand side is empty.